# Are citrus fruits bad for your teeth?

Tags: dentistry

I've heard that the acid in citrus fruits can slowly eat away at your teeth, possibly causing premature loss of teeth.  I've heard that you should be sure to drink water while eating citrus fruit to "wash off the acid" or even generally avoid them altogether.  How true is this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_erosion

Comment: It's true that enamel of the teeth wear off with increased consumptions of citrus fruits. But again the vit c necessity for healthy gums also comes into play, hence a balance has to maintained.